# Regular expression to update string in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

Are any of you good at regular expressions? Here is my problem, I have the following text

```
            POPULAR|00000013|
```

And I need a regular expression to give me just the 13, but the number could be 00001113, so it would need to remove any leading zeros. I want to do this using Notepad ++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, many of us ARE good at Regular Expressions! (we're developers after all!) ;-)

Comment: Can you provide better samples in question of what you're trying to achieve and what you tried and did not work? Have txt like `POPULAR|00000013|` and want to replace, that it looks like...

Comment: POPULAR|00000013|     This is header                                                                       1|2|3|4|5|6            Detail                                                            POPULAR|00000012|       Trailer           Then replace both     POPULAR|00000013| and POPULAR|00000012|   with 13 and 12 respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following Regular Expression:
Find = `POPULAR\|0*(\d+)\|`
Replace = `\1`

Comment: Thanks Chris. I forgot to mention that in the text file I have more than one occurrences  of that text including other information.

Comment: Then use the Replace All option in Notepad++. (PS: If we provide the right answer, then please mark the answer as such and/or increment the up arrow thing so we get credit for helping you. Thanks)

Comment: It didn't work. What I am looking is to replace every occurrences containing POPULR|00000XX| with XX where XX are digits.

Comment: Then just extend my existing suggestion. The only catch is that "|" is a special character and has to be escaped.  I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This regex:

```
0*\K(\d+)
```

will highlight only `13` or any number that follows any number of zeros.

Comment: It didn't work. What I am looking is to replace every occurrences containing POPULR|00000XX| with XX where XX are digits.

Comment: @Dhrubajyotinath: What didn't work? Please, edit your question and add sample text and expected result.